# Generating all the possible dicts from an existing dict in terms of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, combinations, python-itertools

I have a dictionary of

`kwarg = {'a': 0 , 'b': 1 , 'c': 2}`  and I want to produce all the possible alternative dictionaries in terms of values such as:

```
x1={'a': 1 , 'b': 0 , 'c':2}

x2={'a': 1 , 'b': 2 , 'c':0}

x3={'a': 0 , 'b': 2 , 'c':1}

x4={'a': 0 , 'b': 1 , 'c':2}

x5={'a': 2 , 'b': 1 , 'c':0}

x6={'a': 2 , 'b': 0 , 'c':1}
```

but I have 6 elements `(0,1,2,3,4,5)` and need to use python algorytm.

Comment: Tag [python]? --

Comment: yes, i've editted the question

Comment: I mean, use a tag. https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: What does "python algorithm" mean? Are you allowed to use a standard module such as itertools?

Comment: yes i am allowed and really sorry to smash the format!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code in `python3` should do

```
import itertools


def main():
    '''The Main'''

    kwarg = {'a': 0 , 'b': 1 , 'c': 2}
    keys = kwarg.keys()
    for comb in itertools.permutations(kwarg.values()):
        print(dict(zip(keys, comb)))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `python algorithm` mean that you cannot use any predefined function / modue? If yes, the following code may be fine or provide a good starting point:

```
possibilites = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

lstOfDicts = []
for a in possibilites:
    for b in possibilites:
        for c in possibilites:
            lstOfDicts.append({"a" : a, "b" : b, "c" : c})

print(lstOfDicts)
```

Comment: That does not permute, instead, you get all values as '0's on first iteration

Comment: @Krishna this is true and this is how I interpret <<and I want to produce all the possible alternative dictionaries ... but I have 6 elements (0,1,2,3,4,5)>> there is nothing written about a permutation. In case you want to have a permutation, you can use `if a != b != c != a:` before the `lstOfDicts.append` statement.

Comment: @Krishna But I agree that the OP is not to clear here what `alternative dictionaries` means.

Comment: You are right, it is not written.

I interpreted based on the expected output. There are no duplicates.

Comment: Let me upvote your answer. However I will keep my answer. Maybe someone is searching for a way of generating the other dicts including a=0, b=0, c=0 too.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my take on it , more readable and basic :

```
import itertools
kwarg = {'a': 0 , 'b': 1 , 'c': 2}
val=list(kwarg.values())
new=list(itertools.permutations(val))
d=dict()
for i in range(0,len(new)):
    for j in range(0,len(new[i])):
        if j==0:
            d['a']=new[i][j]
        if j==1:
            d['b']=new[i][j]
        if j==2:
            d['c']=new[i][j]
    print(d)
```